# Is there a package or function in R to partition spatial data?

Tags: r, spatial, partition

I want to be able to partition n data points (in practice, n will be very high) into a partition of K subsets (where K will presumably be large as well). In addition, there may not necessarily just be two dimensions. So does anyone know of a good R function/package that can partition a set of n points in a p-dimensional space into a partition having K subsets of approximately equal size?

Below is an example of a plot of n=100 points in a two-dimensional space, where each dimension ranges from 0 to 10. I drew a horizontal line through the median of the y-dimension, and I drew a vertical line through the median of the x-dimension. If I wanted to, I could easily split these data points according to the partition visualized here, with 4 subsets total. So I'm just wondering how to extend this to a more general setting for n, p, and K.
[image: n=100, p=2, K=4]

Comment: KNN Algorithm could be a start. Have a look on this question.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412772/simple-knn-for-spatial-data